# How does Skiller send info in multiplayer games [Android]

Tags: android

I am thinking of using Skiller to manage my multiplayer game and had some questions.  I was hoping to find some tutorials on how to use it, but I'll have to look through the code and the examples to figure it out.  From what I understand, the data sent back and forth in a turn based game (payload) is going to be a string.  This means all my information will need to be condensed into a string and then extracted out on the other end?

For example, Pikachu wants to use Thundershock on Pidgey.
Info to send: MoveName("Thundershock"), movePower("40"), specialAttack("55")
(I could put a key at the beginning to help me figure out what is being sent.)

```
String payload = "Move;Thundershock; 40; 55";
```

Then the other player's game would take that info and figure out the damage done and send that info back

```
payload = "Damage; Super Effective; 23"
```

How does this sound?

```
SKApplication.getInstance().getGameManager().getTurnBasedTools().makeMove(gameId, event, payload, chatline,
new SKListenerInterface<SKGameMoveResponse>(){

@Override
public void onResponse(SKGameMoveResponse response){
    String gameId = response.getGameId();
    eTBGameState state = response.getGameState();
    String payload = response.getPayload();
    String chatline = response.getChatline();
    // handle opponent's move – explained in the next section
}

@Override
public void onError(SKStatusResponse response) {
    // failed to send the move
}
```

});

Here is the [documentation site](http://wiki.skiller-games.com/Playing-finishing-and-rematching-tb-games.ashx)

Comment: Yay @ `Pikachu wants to use Thundershock on Pidgey. `

Comment: I figure Pokemon is an easy example that people can understand. :D

Comment: You may want to have both clients do the calculation to validate the results. Having one do the calculations is an invitation for client mods.